# SQL - JOIN 3 tables but show where data is missing from the middle table

Tags: sql

Given some **Students**:

```
StudentID  Name
---------------
1          James
2          Emma
```

Given some **Exams**:

```
ExamID  Name
---------------
1      Maths
2      English
3      Science
```

Each student will eventually have a **Mark** for each exam, but we're midway through exams and some marks won't exist yet:

```
MarkId StudentId ExamId Grade
-----------------------------
1      1         1      B
2      1         2      A
3      2         1      A
```

How can I query that (middle) Mark table to show all existing marks, but a null row where a student hasn't taken an exam yet?

The results I'm after should look like this:

[image]

I thought I should be able to get this with a RIGHT JOIN, but the 3 JOINs always throw the NULLs away.

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `cross join` to generate the rows and `left join` to bring in the grades:

```
select s.*, e.*, m.grade
from students s cross join
     exams e left join
     marks m
     on m.studentid = s.studentid and m.examid = e.examid;
```